# How to stop a task in ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor once I think it's completed

Tags: java, scheduled-tasks, scheduling, scheduler

I have a ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor with which I schedule a task to run at a fixed rate. I want the task to be running with a specified delay for a maximum of say 10 times until it "succeeds". After that, I will not want the task to be retried. So basically I'll need to stop running the scheduled task when I want it to be stopped, but without shutting down the ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor. Any idea how I'd do that?

Here's some pseudocode -

```
public class ScheduledThreadPoolExecutorTest
{
  public static ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor executor = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(15);  // no multiple instances, just one to serve all requests

  class MyTask implements Runnable
  {
    private int MAX_ATTEMPTS = 10;
    public void run()
    {
      if(++attempt <= MAX_ATTEMPTS)
      {
        doX();
        if(doXSucceeded)
        {
          //stop retrying the task anymore
        }
      }
      else
      { 
        //couldn't succeed in MAX attempts, don't bother retrying anymore!
      }
    }
  }

  public void main(String[] args)
  {
    executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutorTest().new MyTask(), 0, 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 49, accepted):

run this test, it prints `1 2 3 4 5` and stops

```
public class ScheduledThreadPoolExecutorTest {
    static ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor executor = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(15); // no
    static ScheduledFuture<?> t;

    static class MyTask implements Runnable {
        private int attempt = 1;

        public void run() {
            System.out.print(attempt + " ");
            if (++attempt > 5) {
                t.cancel(false);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        t = executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(new MyTask(), 0, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect thanks! I did know about the scheduledfuture but I was trying to use this way:

t = executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(new MyTask(), 0, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
t.cancel(true);

which would never have worked for obvious reasons. Canceling the task inside the task implementation seems about right.

Comment: Thanks. This helped. Interesting to note that this example never exits. I think you need an executor shutdown

Comment: Or rather you need a `t.get()` and an executor shutdown inside a catch block of CancellationException

Comment: Is this approach thread safe? Task execution may reach t.cancel() before it is assigned in the main thread causing NullPointerException.

Answer (score 8):

`CountDownLatch` is an alternative approach. When the thread completes, call `countDown()` on the latch. The calling thread calls `latch.await()` until all threads complete. At that point call `ExecutorService.shutdownNow()` so that your main thread doesn't turn into a zombie.

```
import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class ScheduledThreadPoolExecutorTest {

  static int i = 0;

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    final ScheduledExecutorService executor = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
    final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
    executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(() -> {
        System.out.println(++i);
        if (i > 4) {
          latch.countDown();
        }
    }, 0, 100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    latch.await();
    executor.shutdownNow();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Nicely cancelled outside of thread:

```
public class ScheduleTest {

    @Test
    public void testCancel() throws Exception {
        final ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor EXECUTOR = (ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor) Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(2);
        ScheduledFuture f1 = EXECUTOR.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("Im alive 1");
            }
        }, 0, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        ScheduledFuture f2 = EXECUTOR.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("Im alive 2");
            }
        }, 0, 2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        Thread.sleep(10000);
        f1.cancel(true);
        System.out.println("f1 cancel");
        Thread.sleep(10000);
        f2.cancel(false);
        System.out.println("f2 cancel");
        Thread.sleep(10000);
    }
}
```

Sometimes thread couldn't be cancelled, this solved usually via `volatile boolean isCancelled;`

Comment: Nice Example looking this from a while facing lots of issues because of this.... Thanks :)

Comment: What is difference between `cancel(true)` and `cancel(false)` ?

Comment: You can always have a look at javadoc